# Run using python IntelliJ doesn't work even though run from shell using same interpreter works

Tags: python, intellij-idea, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Running a program using python in IntelliJ  doesn't work even though run from shell using same interpreter works.

IntelliJ autocomplete and referencing the dependent module work

I added the path to the interpreter using virtualenvwrapper add2virtualenv command.

The import is from another module in the same project both module are configured to use the same interpreter.

```
from rx import Observer
ImportError: cannot import name 'Observer'
```

Contents of `pip freeze`

```
cachetools==2.1.0
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
google-auth==1.4.1
idna==2.6
ipaddress==1.0.22
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
kafka-python==1.4.3
kubernetes==6.0.0
MarkupSafe==1.0
oauthlib==2.1.0
pyasn1==0.4.3
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
python-dateutil==2.7.3
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
rsa==3.4.2
Rx==1.6.1
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.22
websocket-client==0.47.0
```

Comment: what is the output of `pip freeze`

Comment: If your file is called `rx.py` you may want to rename it.

Comment: added the pip freeze and the file is named arguer ;)

Answer (score 0):

credit to  @BurhanKhalid comment
It turns out that I had a library named rx in the import path (not the direct import) and there was a clash using IntelliJ. I still don't understand why there is a difference between IntelliJ and shell interpretation.

I fixed it by renaming the library.